# Parse Geometry from Google APIs using $.ajax

Tags: json, ajax, google-api

I am struggling to retrieve the Latitude and Longitude from the Google geocode API. I'm not sure if its how I am printing the data on the page, or if its a problem with actually retrieving the JSON file. But when I run the page nothing shows up. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>        
<p id="output"></p>
    <script>
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=yourkey',
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',

                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.status === 'OK') {
                        let test = $.parseJSON(data);
                        let lat = test.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                        let lng = test.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

                        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = lat + ", " + lng;
                    }
                },
                error: function(msg) {
                    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = 'help';
                }
            });
    </script>
</body>
```

EDIT: Here is the JSON that should be returned from the API call.

```
{
"results" : [
  {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "1600",
           "short_name" : "1600",
           "types" : [ "street_number" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Parkway",
           "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Mountain View",
           "short_name" : "Mountain View",
           "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
           "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "California",
           "short_name" : "CA",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United States",
           "short_name" : "US",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "94043",
           "short_name" : "94043",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 37.4213117,
           "lng" : -122.0839677
        },
        "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 37.4226606802915,
              "lng" : -122.0826187197085
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 37.4199627197085,
              "lng" : -122.0853166802915
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJtYuu0V25j4ARwu5e4wwRYgE",
     "plus_code" : {
        "compound_code" : "CWC8+GC Mountain View, California, United States",
        "global_code" : "849VCWC8+GC"
     },
     "types" : [ "street_address" ]
  }
```

],
   "status" : "OK"
}